# Auto-rotate screen not honoured when turned off

Tags: android

I have a rather strange situation, first of all, I don't ever specify anything for the screenOrientation value of any of my activities.

However, when I turn off "auto-rotate screen" in the global settings of my Xoom running Android 4.0.4, my application, and only my application, continues to auto-rotate.

What am I doing wrong?  Why does my application continue to auto-rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what was causing this.  I had

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

in my manifest.  Taking it out allows it to honour the user's setting.  It also seems declaring on one activity affects any and all activities launched from the offending activity.